# How to execute one machine appium script to another machine(Remote machine)?

Tags: appium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

Is it possible to have Appium running on a remote machine and devices also connected in a same remote machine, and  run the test script from the local machine?

Below code was working fine in local machine with local appium server.
Please help me any one.bcaz i am new to appium.

```
package com.appiumproj.test;    
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Appium {

AppiumDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{

     //Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium

   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.2");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"ZX1D62FPVQ");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.calculatord");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); 
   driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@Test
public void testCal(){


   WebElement two=driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
    two.click();
    WebElement plus=driver.findElement(By.name("+"));
    plus.click();
    WebElement four=driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
    four.click();
    WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(By.name("="));
    equalTo.click();

    WebElement results=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));

    assert results.getText().equals("6"):"Actual value is : "+results.getText()+" did not match with expected value: 6";

    System.out.println("Inside Test Function");
terClass
public void teardown(){


    driver.closeApp();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your appium server in the remote machine on port 4723. Then change the line

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

to

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://IP OF THE REMOTE MACHINE :4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: hi @A.J .thank you for you reply.That is worrking fine in only one device.if i want to run this same script in more than one device then what i need to do for that?

Comment: Do you want to run the same test on multiple devices or multiple tests on multiple devices? Either way you would need selenium grid

Comment: I want to run the same test on multiple devices .

Comment: hi @A.J  
I want to run the same test script on multiple devices

Comment: You would first need to find a way to execute the same test multiple times. Usually people use testNG or JUnit to achieve that. Once thats ready, you can point the tests to selenium hub and tests will run.

Comment: Can you send any link related to selenium grid in appium?

Comment: https://discuss.appium.io/t/connecting-appium-server-to-selenium-grid-for-android/804

Comment: If I want to run this script in out side network.what I need to do?(like public ip?)

Comment: It doesnt make any difference to appium whether the ip is internal or external. As long as you can connect to the ip through the network (intra or internet) appium will run the test.

Comment: my machine ip is like 192.168.X.X but public ip 125.X.X.X is mapped to my machine.if i am hosting any website in that machine, 
i can access that web page by typing public ip url(125.X.X.X/mywebsite).but when i mentioning public ip in my appium script it is saying like invalid address of the remote server.
how to run my script in that machine from any where in the world or any network or any ip segment.How can i achive this?